# Calculating difference between username and email in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, algorithm, email

for security reasons i want the users on my website **not to be able to register a username that resembles their email adress**. Someone with email adress user@domain.com cant register as user or us.er, etc

For example i want this not to be possible:

tester -> tester@mydomain.com (wrong)
tes.ter -> tester@mydomain.com (wrong)
etc.

But i do want to be able to use the following:

tester6 -> tester@mydomain.com (good)
etc.

//edit
tester6 is wrong too. i ment user6 -> tester@mydomain.com (good).

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this, or something as close as possible. I am checking this in javascript, and after that on the server in php.

Ciao!

ps. Maybe there is some jquery plugin to do this, i can't find this so far. The downside tho of using a plugin for this, is that i have to implement the same in php. If it is a long plugin it will take some time to translate.

//Edit again
If i only check the part before the @ they can still use userhotmailcom, or usergmail, etc. If they supply that there email is abvious.

Comment: why would this benifit security?

Comment: In what way is tes.ter worse than tester6?

Comment: Another question - why is tes.ter bad but tester6 good? They both differ by exactly one character. Can you be more specific (formal) about what is "good" and what is not?

Comment: This is more a security issue for me as owner of the website. I want to minimize the amount of communication there is between the users.

Comment: Oooh, sorry, no tester6 has to be user6, ill edit that.

Comment: I wouldnt go this way. I use my name as username on many websites (and in fact ones that won't allow me that have much bigger chance of never seeing me again - their loss :).
And besides, I dont really see how having a username 'tester' would allow others to contact me: should they email tester@yahoo.com, tester@gmail.com or any other of zillions emailable domains out there?

Comment: To be more precise people play against each other to get prizes. If they can get communication with each other very easy this can result in cheating i want to minimize this, i know if people know each other they still can communicate, but i want to make it as hard as possible.

Comment: Yes i know there are zillions emailable domains. But you can try to use just a few email adresses, hotmail,gmail,yahoo. It takes a few secs to do this, You have nothing to loose with sending these email. But it can result in both agreeing to stop to play, and split the prize.

Comment: What about _u_s_e_r_remove_all_underscores_at_some_domain_com?

Comment: *I want to minimize the amount of communication there is between the users.* Just don't publish email adresses in website. Don't damage the UX.

Comment: Email addresses are not published, and _u_s_e_r_remove_all_underscores_at_some_domain_com would be a problem. But i am trying to get the most obvious out of the way. I know it can't be 100% proof.

Comment: How about this username: dossǝɾǝʌǝʇs? If your users want to communicate their email addresses to each other, they'll probably find a way, especially if the site has any kind of commenting or posting functionality. For instance, someone might set up a new site on which people can post their username at your site, and email address. It's really a question of how much time you want to spend delaying them. Btw, if there's no user communication then consider not letting users pick their username. Give them a random string. It's not like it's their identity.

Comment: ok i will keep that in mind,but again, just removing the obvious. And no commenting is possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typically, I use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm to check whether a password looks like a login.

PHP has [a native levenshtein function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) and [here is one written in JavaScript](http://phpjs.org/functions/levenshtein:463).

Comment: Hey, yes i have looked at this method before. It looks a but complicated, and i read it was used for spelling checks, so i skipped it, but i have a look at this link again. thank you

Comment: Awesome +1. If you include this in your answer -- http://phpjs.org/functions/levenshtein:463 -- it'll be more useful.

Comment: Well my answer ended up sucking... have a +1 :D

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
var charsRe = /[.+]/g; // Add your characters here
if (username.replace(charsRe,  '') == email.split('@')[0].replace(charsRe, ''))
    doError();
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to disallow user names that vary from the email address only with periods (`.`), you can remove periods from the user name and compare it with email address.

```
//I don't know php - translating this pseudo code won't be hard

$email = "someone@something.com"
$emailname = $email.substring(0, $email.indexOf('@'));
$uname = "som.e.on.e";
$uname = $uname.replace(/\./g, "");//regex matching a '.' globally

if($uname === $emailname)
  showInvalidNameErrorMessage();
```

Modified regex to prevent hyphens and underscores `/[\-._]/g`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am a newbie PHP developer. But the answer I have in my mind is, wouldn't it be great if you just allow them to register only with their email address (which won't be shared with others) and then ask for their first name and last name separately and only show their first name within public contents (i.e. Blogs, etc). I am not an expert in programming and if I am wrong please correct me and still I couldn't understand what you by security for you. Sorry for the bad English, I am not a native English speaker.